# Error : "module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed"

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols

Getting this error while running my program. I searched the Internet to find `QtQuick.Controls` but couldn't get any resolution.
How can I install this?

Comment: What is your OS, Qt version and how Qt was installed on your machine?

Comment: OS was Ubuntu 12.10, now upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10. Qt version earlier was 4.8 and now 5.1! QtQuick 2.0 works but `QtQuick.Controls` shows as not installed.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 is still on 5.0.

Comment: That's correct. its showing 5.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely using an old version of Qt. The `QtQuick.Controls` module was introduced in Qt 5.1:

- https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qtquickcontrols-index.html

Comment: I have Qt 5.0.2, how can I upgrade it to Qt 5.1 from OS Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: So that's the reason you're getting the error you've asked about. How to upgrade is a different question, which I suggest asking on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have upgraded to   Qt Creator 3.0.0
Based on Qt 5.2.0 (GCC 4.6.1, 32 bit)

Built on Dec 10 2013 at 11:47:52... still the same error.. please help!

Answer (score 6):

this command fixed my problem.

```
sudo apt -y install qml-module-qtquick-controls
```

Answer (score 4):

For a **Qt 6** on Ubuntu, the fix is:

```
sudo apt -y install qml6-module-qtquick-controls
```

You might want to have other modules as well, e.g.:

```
sudo apt -y install qml6-module-qtqml-workerscript
sudo apt -y install qml6-module-qtquick-templates
sudo apt -y install qml6-module-qtquick-layouts
```

Answer (score 1):

Another cause of this 'module "Qt*" is not installed' class of problems on Ubuntu at least is the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` not being set. It should include the path to the lib directory of your Qt installation, e.g.

```
if [ "x$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" = "x" ]; then
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/lib
else
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/username/Qt5.4.1/5.4/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

For those getting this issue while static building with vcpkg and CMAKE, I followed these steps:

1. `.\vcpkg install qt5-quickcontrols:<target>`

I was building statically on a x64 windows platform so my target was `x64-windows-static`, more info [about the target flag here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/examples/installing-and-using-packages)

2. In my CMakeLists.txt, below `target_link_libraries()` I added:

> qt5_import_qml_plugins(${PROJECT_NAME}
> INCLUDE
> Qt5::qtquickcontrolsplugin)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer which covers my case since it's different from what the other two answers give as feedback.

I've built Qt 5.7 for the Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Jessie). From my notebook I transferred a simplistic QML-based project which worked there. However after building the project on my Pi and starting it (note that QML problems often don't show up when you compile and link stuff) I got that very same error. Obviously the version here was not an issue.

The problem was that for some reason I haven't built the **qtquickcontrols** and **qtquickcontrols2** modules in the source tree of my Qt. Luckily I used an USB flash drive for storing the sources and also where I have build my Qt version from these so it was just a matter of `cd`ing inside the respective module directories, executing `qmake` followed by `make -j4` (for faster building use parallel `make`) and finally `make install`.